# DRY in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 8 controllers using 12 common functions. but 3-4 functions are different in each of them. How can I not repeat myself in each of these? I am using a service common to each of these controllers. My code:

```
app.controller("ArticleController",['$scope','$http','dataService',function($scope,$http,dataService){

$scope.comments={};
$scope.articles = {articles:[]};
$scope.reachedEnd = false;
$scope.getArticles //implemented differently for each of the controllers
//Here it is used to fetch latest articles
/* common 12 functions 
   to deal with dom events. On addition of new comments, upvotes, etc
*/
function getArticlesSuccess(articles){
    articles.articles.forEach(function(article){
        $scope.articles.articles.push(article);
    });
    $scope.reachedEnd = articles.reachedEnd;
}

$scope.addToReadingList = function(id,userid){
    dataService.addToReadingList(id,userid);
};

$scope.removeFromReadingList = function(id,userid){
    dataService.removeFromReadingList(id,userid);
};

$scope.upvote = function(id,userid){
    upvoteIncrementer(id,userid);
    dataService.upvote(id);
};

$scope.deleteComment = function(commentId){
    dataService.deleteComment(commentId);
};

var upvoteIncrementer = function(id,userid){
    console.log(id);
    $scope.articles.articles.forEach(function(article){
        console.log(article);
        if(article && article._id === id && !article.votes.set){
            if(article.votes.down.indexOf(userid)>-1){
                article.votes.down.splice(article.votes.down.indexOf(userid));
                console.log('removed vote');
            }
            article.votes.up.push(userid);
            article.votes.set = true;
        }
    });
}


$scope.downvote = function(id,userid){
    downvoteIncrementer(id,userid);
    dataService.downvote(id);
}

var downvoteIncrementer = function(id,userid){
    console.log(id);
    $scope.articles.articles.forEach(function(article){
        console.log(article);
        if(article && article._id === id && !article.votes.set){
            console.log(article);
            if(userid in article.votes.up){
                article.votes.up.splice(article.votes.up.indexOf(userid));
                console.log('removed vote');
            }
            article.votes.down.push(userid);
            article.votes.set = true;
        }
    });
}


$scope.showComments = function(id){
    dataService.getComments(id).then(function(data){
        $scope.articles.articles.forEach(function(article){
            if(article._id === id ){
                article.fetchedComments = data.comments;
            }
        });
        console.log($scope.fetchedComments);
    });
}

$scope.commentForm = function(id,user,contents) {
    dataService.postComments(id,user,contents).then(function(x){
    $scope.articles.articles.forEach(function(article){
            if(article._id === id ){
                article.fetchedComments.push(x);
                console.log(article.fetchedComments);
            }
        });
    });
}
}]);
```

code for another controller:

```
app.controller("ArticleController",['$scope','$http','dataService',function($scope,$http,dataService){
$scope.comments={};
$scope.articles = {articles:[]};
$scope.reachedEnd = false;
$scope.getArticles //implemented differently for each of the controllers
//Here it is used to fetch top articles by the day
/* common 12 functions */
}]);
```

**EDIT**: Added dataservice.js

```
(function(){

angular.module('newstalk')
    .factory('dataService',['$http','$q',dataService]);

function dataService($http,$q){
    return {
        getArticles : getArticles,
        postComments : postComments,
        addToReadingList : addToReadingList,
        getReadingList : getReadingList,
        upvote : upvote,
        downvote : downvote,
        getComments : getComments,
        removeFromReadingList : removeFromReadingList,
        deleteComment : deleteComment
    };

    function getArticles(numsRecieved){
        return $http({
            method:'get',
            url:'/api/articles/'+parseInt(numsRecieved/10)
        })
        .then(sendResponse);
    }

    function deleteComment(commentId){
        $http.delete('/api/delete/comment/'+commentId)
            .then(function(response){console.log(response);});
    }

    function sendResponse(response){
            return response.data;
    }

    function sendResponseComments(response){
            return response.data;
    }

    function postComments(id,user,contents){
        var uid = user._id;
        var uname=user.name;
        var c =  contents;
        var data = {
            content: c,
            id: uid,
            name:uname
        };
        console.log(data);
        return $http.post('/api/article/'+id,data).then(sendResponse);
    }
    function addToReadingList(id,userid){
        var data = {
            id: id,
            user: userid
        };
        $http.post('/api/user/add/'+userid,data);   
    }

    function removeFromReadingList(id,userid){
        var data = {
            id: id,
            user: userid
        };
        $http.post('/api/user/rem/'+userid,data);   
    }

    function getReadingList(userid){
        console.log('/api/readinglist/0');
        return $http({
            method:'get',
            url:'/api/readinglist/0'
        })
        .then(sendResponse);
    }           
    function upvote(id){
        return $http({
            method:'post',
            url:'/api/article/up/'+id
        });
    }
    function downvote(id){
        return $http({
            method:'post',
            url:'/api/article/down/'+id
        });
    }
    function getComments(id){
        return $http({
            method:'get',
            url:'/api/article/comments/'+id
        })
        .then(sendResponseComments);
    }

}
})()
```

Please suggest a way so that I can reduce the code and need to make changes in only one area to have effect everywhere.

Comment: Explain more about your logic. What dataService does? From where is being loaded the data?

Comment: deleteComment, getArticles, etc are being used in many controllers? Or each one is used in just one controller?

Comment: They are being used in many. The getArticles is different for each of the controllers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna write a answer about the design of the code.

Comment: @AyushGupta I need to get to sleep. I'll check this out tomorrow and try to help if needed. You should explain what you're trying to do with `getArticles` and what that has to do with the DOM.

Comment: @m59 The `getArticles` function is just fetching the articles from the server, using different urls for different controllers and plugging the fetched data in the scope.

Comment: @AyushGupta I updated my answer to specifically address your previous comment. Please remember to include those kinds of relevant details in your posts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function as a service and have that function return an object with the functions you need to reuse across controllers. You would call that function in each controller, passing parameters to configure the functions according to which controller you're using.

```
app.factory('myStuff', function($http) {
  return function(urlForController) {
    return {
      foo: function() {
        // use the parameters in your functions
        return $http.get(urlForController);
      },
      bar: //etc
    };
  };
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myStuff) {
  // call the service function, passing in the controller specific parameters to configure the returned object
  $scope.myStuff = myStuff('/whatever');
});
```

You can even pass the controller's `$scope` into the service and let those functions manipulate it you need.

```
$scope.myStuff = mystuff($scope, '/whatever');

// the service:
return function(scope, urlForController) {
```

Comment: I am using that. The `dataService` is for that only. Still I'll have to call it in each controller. As every function in the controller deals with a different DOM element.

Comment: @AyushGupta He covered your main question pretty clearly. If you have several questions, ask them separately.

Comment: _use a function as a service and have that function return an object with the functions you need to reuse_. This is perfect!